# Android jetpack compose Material 3 Unable to align checkbox text

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox, text-alignment, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am using Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1.

I am fairly new.  I was trying out the checkbox in Compose with Material3 in Android.  I am not able to align the text next to check box. Please help.  Here is the code and an screenshot image of the emulator screen.

1. project level build.gradle firl

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.2.0'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
}
```

2. module level build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.test'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.2.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha11'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
}
```

3. MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TestTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Test()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Test() {
    Row(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp)
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(3.dp)
        )
        {
            Checkbox(
                checked = true,
                onCheckedChange = { },
                modifier = Modifier.absoluteOffset((-12).dp, 0.dp)
            )
            Text(
                text = "Check me",
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 18.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Left
            )
        }

        TextButton(
            onClick = { },
            modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 0.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Right text",
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 18.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Right
            )
        }


    }
}
```

I have attached a screen shot of the emulator screen to show how the text is aligned.

Question:

1. How can I align the text "Check me" along with check box.
2. How can I bring it closer to check box.

Please help.

[image: Here is the screen shot of the emulator screen after I run the app. Notice that the text next to the check box appears displaced upwards.]

I tried to place text next to checkbox in my android studio material 3 project.  The text is not aligned in line with the checkbox.

Comment: In the `check me` text composable function pass the modifier's align property and align Center Vertically , like this modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertical)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you this guide to align:  https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/alignment-lines

I was playing around with your code, and here is what I get:

[image]

```
fun Modifier.firstBaselineToTop(
    firstBaselineToTop: Dp
) = layout { measurable, constraints ->
    // Measure the composable
    val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)

    // Check the composable has a first baseline
    check(placeable[FirstBaseline] != AlignmentLine.Unspecified)
    val firstBaseline = placeable[FirstBaseline]

    // Height of the composable with padding - first baseline
    val placeableY = firstBaselineToTop.roundToPx() - firstBaseline
    val height = placeable.height + placeableY
    layout(placeable.width, height) {
        // Where the composable gets placed
        placeable.placeRelative(0, placeableY)
    }
}

@Composable
fun Test() {
    Row(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp)
    ) {
        Row {
            Checkbox(
                checked = true,
                onCheckedChange = { },
                modifier = Modifier.absoluteOffset((-12).dp, 0.dp)
            )
            Text(
                text = "Check me",
                Modifier.padding(vertical =10.dp),
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 18.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Left
            )
        }
        TextButton(
            onClick = { },
            modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 0.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Right text",
                Modifier.firstBaselineToTop(16.dp),
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 18.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Right
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  And it works.  I had to do the same to the other Text Composable that displays "Check me" to align all three.
The second part of my question is still open.  I would like to reduce the gap between the checkbox and the text "Check me".  I also would like move the check box  to the left and closer to the start position.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Nazir you can set the custom size of the icon via `Modifier.size()`. You can try this code `Checkbox(modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp).padding(0.dp).absoluteOffset(y = 11.dp))`

Comment: How do you get those guidelines in the design preview of the composable.  In my case the preview does not have these guidelines

Comment: just hover your mouse cursor over the view and the lines will appear

Comment: The guidelines must be some Android thing... I don't see them in InelliJ in a desktop app.

Answer (score 2):

For that you have to align both the text Center Vertically , Below is the full code.

```
@Composable
fun Test() {

    var selected by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(10.dp),
    ) {

        Row(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
            Checkbox(checked = selected, onCheckedChange = { selected = it })
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
            Text(
                text = "Check me",
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 18.sp,
                color = Color.Black,
                modifier = Modifier.align(CenterVertically)
            )
        }
        Text(
            text = "Right text",
            fontSize = 18.sp,
            color = Color.Blue,
            modifier = Modifier.align(CenterVertically)
        )
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Simple and clean

Comment: it will stop working, when your text will be 2 lines long

Comment: remove spaceBetween property from Row and add weight(1F) modifier to child Row's composable.